# Memory Leak In line of code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

My app is working fine, but when I run instrument for checking for leaks, it shows me a leak at this line of code, in purple with a 100.0% mark:

```
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Here's the method containing this line:

```
-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh" ofType:@"lproj"];

    if(selectedLanguage==French)
    {
        FinalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.xyz.com/api_com.php?page_id=%d",IDValue];
        url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:FinalString];
    }
    else if(selectedLanguage==German)
    {
        FinalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.x.com/api_com.php?page_id=%d",IDValue];
        url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:FinalString];
    }
    else if(selectedLanguage==Nepali)
    {
        FinalString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.xy.com/api_com.php?page_id=%d",IDValue];
        url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:FinalString];
    }
    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [url release];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    parser = [[NewsParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];
    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
    return str;
}
```

Here's my `ViewDidLoad` method from which `languageSelectedStringForKey` is called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    appDelegate = (ProgAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    IDValue = 1;
    textLabel.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Welcome to Advance Localization"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

What is causing this leak, and how can I fix it?

this is dealloc method:-

```
- (void)dealloc
{

    [xmlParser release];
    [parser release];
    [nibLoadedCell release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Do you have that leak profiling on a device with iOS 6? I had a similar leak and when profiling on a device with iOS 5, the leak disappears. So it could point to a problem in Apple's source code?

Answer (score 3):

Do you ever call

```
[xmlParser release];
```

?

If not, you should release it when you no longer need it.  Perhaps in the dealloc method of the same class in which that line appears.

Comment: sory Matthew for my incomplete information i'm already release the xmlParser in my dealloc method plz you can check in my dealloc method i actually update my information above...thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make NewsParser parser an instance variable and release it in the dealloc. Above, you init it, but you don't release it. Of course, you can't because it's a delegate of xmlParser. So, to make sure the object is retained, then properly released, it must be an ivar.

Comment: It is an instance variable (called `parser`) and it's released in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: oops that's what comes from doing two things at once! Right then, my guess would be that xmlParser is init'd somewhere else in your code. For example if your languageSelectedStringForKey method is called twice then the existing reference to xmlParser would be leaked. As would any other objects such as "parser" for which you are not checking non-nil before init'ing again.

Answer (score 0):

You never release FinalString (at least not in the code you posted)

this is held in the URL, which is held by the parser :)

---

Also, have you considered what would happen if this function is called twice?

Each time you say

```
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

you would leak the previous xmlParser ;)

If you are allocating to an instance variable, you have to remember to release the previous object i.e.

```
[xmlParser release];
xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: See my edit - I had another idea :) What happens if this function is called twice?