# Memory Leak In Code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Memory Leak In line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441913/memory-leak-in-line-of-code)

This code is works fine but it gives me a memory leak in one of the line of code the line is which showing leak indicated by purple color in the instrument by mentioning 100.0% the line is

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

i'll show you my code this is appdelegate file didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.xyz.com/news.php?page_id=1"];

    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [url release];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    NewsParser *parser = [[NewsParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    else
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    [parser release];
    [xmlParser release];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and this further code is from the NewsParser file NSXMLParser Methods:-

```
- (NewsParser *) initXMLParser {
    [super init];
    appDelegate = (TWAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"posts"]) {
        appDelegate.newsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else
    {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"page"])
        {

            aNewsInfo = [[NewsInfo alloc] init];
            aNewsInfo.page = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];


        }
        if(![elementName compare:@"smallimage"])
        {
            currentElementValue = [NSMutableString string];

        }
        if(![elementName compare:@"largeimage"])
        {
            currentElementValue = [NSMutableString string];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Processing Element :%@",elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 
    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"posts"])
        return;
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"page"]) {
        [appDelegate.newsArray addObject:aNewsInfo];
        NSLog(@"%d",[appDelegate.newsArray count]);
        NSLog(@"%@",aNewsInfo.title);
        NSLog(@"%@",aNewsInfo.fulltext);
        [aNewsInfo release];
        aNewsInfo = nil;
    }
    else {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"smallimage"])
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentElementValue];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
            [aNewsInfo setSmallImageData:image];
        }
        if(![elementName compare:@"largeimage"])
        {
            NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:currentElementValue];
            NSData *data =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            [data release];
            [aNewsInfo setLargeImageData:image];
        }
        [aNewsInfo setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
        [currentElementValue release];
        currentElementValue = nil;
    }
}
```

Any one plz tell me how to overcome this leak i'm about to submit my app on the app store but this is the only leak plz give your suggestions.

Thanks...

Comment: initXMLParser should have `self = [super init];`, but that's not your leak.  usually after calling init like that you have `if (self) { ... } return self;`

Comment: Can you include your dealloc?  If you aren't releasing variables in there you will get leaks.

Answer (score 5):

You can run the static analyzer which will usually show you the cause for the leak. It's 
"Analyze" in the menu, next to the "Build" command.

Answer (score 2):

You know if you just use `@property` and `@synthesize` and then use the getters and setters correctly you can reduce this issue occuring about 99% of the time.

This line looks like one of the most suspect to me

```
appDelegate.newsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

that is assuming that `newsArray` is declared as a property with `retain`, in which case you would be allocating an `NSMutableArray` which will have a retain of +1 and then setting it with a setter which (if is set as retain) will give a further +1.

This line doesn't look to great to me either

```
currentElementValue = [NSMutableString string];
```

You are assigning an autoreleased `NSMutableString` to an ivar without the ivar taking a retain on it. This could lead to more difficult to track issues later.

Some one pointed out that the init method is not properly written - it is not the problem but should still be fixed. It should look something more like this

```
- (NewsParser *)initXMLParser 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        appDelegate = (TWAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Yep, developing a style where you use properties consistently and religiously will go a long way to reducing memory bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Do the following

```
NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]; 
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
```

The initWithContentsOfURL does not properly release the url, hence the memory leak.
Luckily initWithData does not have this issue, providing a neat way of working around this memory leak.

Comment: How does this resolve any issues? It's essentially the same except you have introduced two auto released objects and chosen a slightly different initializer method.

Comment: There is a long know issue with NSXMLParser not releasing the URL object. This way you are in control of the URL being released by ARC

Comment: It might be worth adding that to your answer with any citations so that people like myself don't question if/why it works. Also the OP is not using ARC as there are release calls so these would just be plain old auto release objects with no clever releasing when the objects are no longer required.

Comment: I stand corrected on ARC, you are totally right. Added some info to answer on why this works.